# How to handle a missing nested List within a Json which containing multiple lists

Tags: c#, json, list

I Have a Json file that contains several list objects within the parent.  In my case the parent object is a list named data.  Within data I have several elements that contain data such as Name, status, title...  Nested within each of these elements is another list named "categories"  I write the value of these elements to a class using the code snippet shown here:

```
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
for (int i = 0; i < dict.Values.Sum(x => x.Count); i++)
{
  foreach (var item in dict)
  {
      eSummary summary = new eSummary();
      summary.evidenceId = (dict["data"][i]["evidenceId"]);
      summary.idExternal = (dict["data"][i]["idExternal"]);
      //summary.category = (dict["data"][i]["categories"][0]);
      summary.dateUploaded = Convert.ToDateTime((dict["data"][i]["dateUploaded"]));
  }
}
```

All is fine until I reach a record that has no value pair in the Categories list.  Apparently if there is no elements in the categories list the list is not included in the json parent Data, and my code crashed on the line I have commented out.

So my problem is how can I handle the situation with a missing list object from the parent list??

Right now I am handing it with a try catch block with nothing in the catch block, but figured there must be a better way.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Okay thanks I'll remember that next time I post a question

Comment: You should check if categories is null first, and if it is, set the default value you'd like in that case. So if e.g. you want the category to be set to "" in case there is no category list in the parent data, you'd write:

`summary.category = dict["data"][i]["categories"] == null ? "" : dict["data"][i]["categories"][0]`

Comment: I tried that but the code crashes. The problem is if categories is null the parent element does not include the category object.  So I can't check the status of a object that does not exists in the particular element.

Answer (score 0):

I handled this problem using a try catch block as follows:

```
try
{
  Data.Category = (dict["data"][i]["categories"][0]);
}
catch (Exception)
{
   Data.Category = "";
}
```